# Heroku duplicate key value violates unique constraint (django)

Tags: python, django, heroku

Today I deployed my django app on Heroku for the first time (following [this](https://youtu.be/6DI_7Zja8Zc) tutorial).

The problem is that when I want to modify or add something to the database, I get an Integrity Error which says:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_professore_pkey"
```

Where Professore is the name of the Model I tried to modify.

I’ve searched a bit online and I’ve seen that probably is because I developed the app on my PC using SQLite and now, on Heroku, it uses PostgreSQL, and those 2 databases works differently.
Actually, I don’t have a lot of experience with databases (almost no experience) so I don’t know how to fix this... Maybe modifying something on the *Professore* model? Or typing something in the Heroku console?

[This is the error screen I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM6Oe.jpg), if you need it to help me :)

Thanks in advance and tell me if I wasn’t clear on something (I’m new to StackOverflow too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resync your primary key fields in Postgres.

You can access your DB by this command

`python manage.py dbshell`

Just check table name
`your_database_name=# \dt`

executing below command

```
SELECT setval('table_name_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name)+1);
```

Comment: Thank you, and do you know where can I find `your_database_name`, `table_name_id_seq` and `table name` On Heroku?

Comment: To access db run python manage.py dbshell, you will come to db, then type \dt, you will get all the table names on console.

Answer (score 0):

4yrs later

Faced the same issue, it's that gunicorn has multiple workers when you're launching it and they're all scrambling to do a db.create

You can temporarily handle it with WEB_CONCURRENCY=1

```bash
heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
```

Or set it in your heroku dashboard ≥ app > settings > Config vars

Alternatively and probably easier to control is to use a script that you execute from the Procfile

```
migrate: python create_db.py
web: gunicorn app:app
```